# Find coordinate on boundary of BW image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to find a specific point on an image in MATLAB, where the object I need to measure 'starts'. It's an image of a droplet laying on surface, and I would like to know how to find the x coordinate where the droplet starts.

[image]

I have a large dataset of these kind of images and the coordinates where the droplet starts is different for every image.

So my question is, is there a way to find the coordinates of this 'starting point' in MATLAB?

Comment: Can you tell us what is "starting point" for you in the image? The first column where there is a black pixel? If that is the case, have you considerend finding exactly that?

Comment: @Ander Biguri Yeah of course sorry! With starting point I mean where the droplet starts so you first see the white line thats the glass. Then when you follow this line there is a point where the white line starts to go up. And that is the point I need thats where the first pixel of the droplet starts. So the first column where the boundary starts to go up.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for your quick response! I thought about that too, but I couldn't figure out how. Could you maybe give me a hint or show me an example on how to do this?

Comment: Grab the lowest black point of each column, so you suddenly have a function, not an image. Compute the numerical derivative (e.g. with `diff`). If that gets large, it means the droplet starts. The success of this method will depend on how your other images look like though. This is why its better you do it, because a solution for this image may not work for the other images, and the goal here is that you learn how to do it, not for us to provide a solution. Update your post with what you've tried if you can't make it work.

Comment: @YvesDaoust how to turn what you described into code haha. I had the same idea, but I have been struggling to make it work this whole day without any success :(. Maybe you can help me out a little more, would really appreciate it!

Comment: @YvesDaoust agree, it was just a "quick" solution that may work

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes I am able to find a list of the xy points on the whole boundary. Now I need to write code that gives me the x point as soon as the y value changes a certain amount of pixels over a certain interval of x right? This is where I am struggling. Maybe use a while loop?

Answer (score -1):

I managed to do it. This is probably not the best way, but it seems to work!

```
            % Check X coordinate of start droplet
         [B] = bwboundaries(FBW, 'noholes');
         for k = 1:length(B)
             boundary = B{k};
             for l = 70:length(boundary)
                 dY(l) = (boundary(l,1) - boundary((l-15),1));
                 startDropletH = find([dY(:)] < -2, 1, "first")-5;
             end
         end
```

It first stores all the points on the border, then calculates and stores the `dY` over 15 X points, from which it looks up the first time `dY<-2`, which indicates the droplet is starting.

Comment: What if you mirror the sample image horizontally ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust don't see how that would benefit this solution, would you mind to explain that?

Comment: Ah I see, but in my case there is no need to mirror or change anything to the images besides crop a specific part and binarize them. But yes the code needs some adjustments if thats a requirement.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, the wire the droplets are sitting on is completely static at least for each series of measurements (120 images). Also the camera is fixed in the same position all the time. I have been analyzing a lot of images past week and for me it works really well around 95% of the time with really low user input :)